# Ladder doesn't allow paths through it - why?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm attempting to create a direct hiking route via a ladder on OpenRouteService (which uses OpenStreetMap), but the route cannot be created.

Here is the ladder (Thronleiter) on OSM:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/edit#map=21/47.49255/13.23794

I found other ladders that *do* work here:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/edit#map=19/47.36060/9.75714

I found that those ladders use type ‘steps’ instead of ‘line’, so I changed that, but it didn’t seem to have any effect. (or how long does it take for changes to propagate?)

Other than that, I don’t see any significant differences between the two - but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

The routes on OpenRouteService:

works:
https://openrouteservice.org/directions?n1=47.360603&n2=9.756604&n3=16&a=47.36047,9.756128,47.360702,9.75749&b=2b&c=0&g1=-1&g2=0&k1=en-US&k2=km

doesn’t work:
https://openrouteservice.org/directions?n1=47.493015&n2=13.23682&n3=16&a=47.492229,13.23793,47.492972,13.238547&b=2b&c=0&g1=-1&g2=0&k1=en-US&k2=km

Answer (score 0):

You added the [ladder](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/296879506) just one hour ago (by changing highway=via_ferrata to highway=steps). Changes are not immediately recognized by all end services. Especially routers take a longer time to process them (days, sometimes weeks or even longer). You can check other [OSM-based online routers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) if they already did catch up with the new data.

Note that this question is not suitable for StackOverflow since it is not a programming question. Consider asking these questions at http://help.openstreetmap.org instead.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that there was a forum over at OSM,thanks! Ladder still doesn't work. I'll ask there!

Comment: I guess OpenRouteService has still old data. It works with other OSM-based routing engines, see for example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=graphhopper_foot&route=47.49279%2C13.23817%3B47.49230%2C13.23787#map=19/47.49254/13.23796&layers=N

Comment: Yes, I am being told that they will update the data next week.